# I'm unable to add a foreign key

Tags: sql, postgresql

I created this two table in a postgres database im trying to add the first uuid key in the second table as a foreign key but this error pops up

> column "book_id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist

This is the first table

```
CREATE TABLE books(
book_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
book_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
book_categ VARCHAR(255),
book_price FLOAT
);
```

This is the second table where im trying to add the foreign key

```
CREATE TABLE reader(
reader_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
reader_fullname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
reader_CIN VARCHAR(255),
reader_adress VARCHAR(255),
FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id)
);
```

Comment: Foreign keys should be to a primary key.  You haven't defined a primary key.

Comment: i thought when i declare it as a uuid it will also be a primary key by default

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Actually a `FOREIGN KEY` has to be to a  `UNIQUE` key or combination of columns that is declared `UNIQUE`. A `PRIMARY KEY` has a `UNIQUE` attribute so it also qualifies.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver . . . A foreign key **should** be to a primary key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple issues in your code.  I would suggest:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
    book_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4() PRIMARY KEY,
    book_title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    book_categ VARCHAR(255),
    book_price NUMERIC(20, 4)
);

CREATE TABLE readers (
    reader_id uuid DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4(),
    reader_fullname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    reader_CIN VARCHAR(255),
    reader_address VARCHAR(255),
    book_id uuid,
    FOREIGN KEY (book_id) REFERENCES books(book_id)
);
```

Notes:

- You need the primary key definition in the first table.
- You need to define the column in the second table.
- `FLOAT` is a bad choice for a monetary amount.  You should use numeric/decimal.

I also don't know what you are trying to model.  But my suspicion is that you want one table for `readers` with one row per "reader" and then another table for `readerBooks` with one row per book that a reader reads.